Http failure response for http://localhost:5001/APIS/User: 0 Unknown Error
i am getting empty response
GET http://localhost:5001/APIS/User net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
how can i solve this issue .it is arriving for first time when i create my angular app and call http request
    this.http.get("http://localhost:5001/APIS/User").subscribe({
      next: response => this.Users = response,
      error: err=> console.log(err),
      complete: ()=> console.log("Request is completed")

